# efficient Index for huge data

Tags: mongodb

I have column where I save phone numbers. I have added an index and the query is using it as expected. But is this index efficient? Will it be still fast when I have millions of records?

```js
> db.testData.ensureIndex( { phone: 1 } )

> db.testData.find({"phone":"267884851"}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor phone_1",
        "nscanned" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1,
        "n" : 1,
        "millis" : 0,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "phone" : [
                        [
                                "267884851",
                                "267884851"
                        ]
                ]
        }
}
> db.testData.find({"phone":"267884851"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("537ae3b8c461dc377b5d99a6"), "x" : 211, "phone" : [ "27848690", "267884851" ] }
```

Comment: What do you see where you run db.testData.find({"phone":"267884851"},{"phone":1, _id:0}).explain() Ideally, you want an "indexOnly": true to appear there. Other than that, what Devest says is spot on.

Comment: The point about strings and numbers is quite valid. If you need formatting of the number then do that in code with a template. Additionally part of the point of phone numbers should be that they are **unique** otherwise you are possibly calling someone else. So make your index unique as you intend to get exact matches. The comment about index only is a little off. But where possible, if you have another commonly used field that you can return as the only result field along with "phone" then add that and you have a covered  index, which is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be efficient , as now the search of phone number will start using the Binary Search with has running complexity of **log(N) where N is number of records so in case you have 10000000 records it will in worst case take 24 iteration** to find the record if it exists, so is good enough.

I was thinking because you are keeping your phone number as string , will it be better if you keep it as integer if possible which should have better in case of string compare.